# How would I use Scrapy to web scrape data on wtatennis.com?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

The response provided using Scrapy Shell shows that the majority of data that I wish to scrape is not available until after the page loads. Additionally, the page appears to use lazy loading, so the data is not available until scroll points are hit.

Is it possible to use Python Scrapy to extract data from wtatennis.com and similar websites?

If so, what needs to be done to show the content?

Page example: https://www.wtatennis.com/tournaments

Comment: You won't be able to scrape until its load. You can use selenium [SELENIUM][1]


  [1]: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html

You can also load pages without javascript it would be faster.

Comment: What are the data needs? There is an API which could be re-engineered without having to use selenium.

Comment: An API would also work! Do you know where I can find this API?